# Finding All Bounded-Length Simple Cycles in a Directed Graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graph, cyclic-graph

I'm looking for the implementation of any fast algorithm that finds all bounded-length simple cycles in a Directed Graph. I've tried to find all simple cycles without length constraint using java jgrapht library and then filter them, but it's very inefficient for the graph that I'm working with.

Comment: Inefficient?  What are your specifications?  How many vertices and edges does your graph posses?  What is your performance reuirement?

Comment: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0205007